# vba textbox from browse

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA and struggling with something that I'm fairly certain is basic. In Excel, I'd like to select 'browse', choose a folder and the folder populates in a textbox.

The browse is working and will allow me to select a folder, but I can't get the textbox populated with the folder selected.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim FName As String
 FName = BrowseFolder(Caption:="Select A Folder", InitialFolder:="C:\MyFolder")
 If FName = vbNullString Then
    Debug.Print "No folder selected."
 Else
    Debug.Print "Folder Selected: " & FName
 End If
End Sub



Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    TextBox2.Text = FName.SelectItems(0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make **FName** *Global.*

**Dim** it as *Public* in a standard module.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim FName As String
 FName = BrowseFolder(Caption:="Select A Folder", InitialFolder:="C:\MyFolder")
 If FName = vbNullString Then
    Debug.Print "No folder selected."
 Else
    Debug.Print "Folder Selected: " & FName
    Textbox2.value = FName.SelectItems(0)
 End If
End Sub
```